# When match a char in a csv field, replace it by the column title concatenate with another filed on the same rank

Tags: csv, replace, sed, awk, concatenation

I have a csv that contain domain list and a tick on each extension column i possess :

```
num;domaine;fr;com;xxx;net;eu;org;info;asia;com.tw;hk;mobi;net.cn;org.cw;tw
1;mydomain1;x;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2;mydomain2;x;x;x;x;;;;;;;;;;
3;mydomain3;x;x;x;x;x;x;;;;;;;;*
```

I'd like to create a text file from this csv that contain all the domain.extension :

```
mydomain1.fr
mydomain2.fr
mydomain2.com
mydomain2.xxx
mydomain2.net
mydomain3.fr
mydomain3.com
mydomain3.xxx
etc.
```

i made some dirty thing with sed and case but i'm sure a better brain could give me some tips to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try so far (with sed), and why were you not happy with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  awk -F';' 'NR==1{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)d[i]=$i;next}
                       {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="x")print $2"."d[i]}' file
mydomain1.fr
mydomain2.fr
mydomain2.com
mydomain2.xxx
mydomain2.net
mydomain3.fr
mydomain3.com
mydomain3.xxx
mydomain3.net
mydomain3.eu
mydomain3.org
```

shorter version:

```
awk -F';' '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)if(NR==1)d[i]=$i;else if($i=="x")print $2"."d[i]}' file
```

Comment: A one line solution, i was sure that someone clever would produce so. It works perfectly. thanks.